# Apache with Angular2 - 404 Not Found

Tags: apache, angular, bitnami

I have deployed an Angular2 application on an AWS server with Bitnami image.
The application is served by Apache (configured with a virtual host on port 8080) and works fine as long as I start from `index.html`. If I want to access a different page (which has been configured in the `RouteConfig`)  I get a `404 not found` error.
Here is the configuration of the virtual server:

```
Listen 8080
<VirtualHost _default_:8080>
  DocumentRoot "/opt/bitnami/apps/MyApp"
<Directory  "/opt/bitnami/apps/MyApp">
Options All
Require all granted
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 6):

Add `.htaccess` file to your root folder. I'm using this:

```
# BEGIN ServeStatic

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>

# END ServeStatic
```

it serves `index.html` for all requests that would cause 404...

Comment: thanks, it works. I had only to specify `AllowOverride All` in the `<Directory>` section

Answer (score 1):

```
    ServerName angular2ssipl


    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/SSIPL-Angular

    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
    <Directory /var/www/html/SSIPL-Angular/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride None
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
            Require all granted

            RewriteEngine on
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
            RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
            RewriteRule ^(.*) /index.html [NC,L]
    </Directory>
```

Comment: Yes, It is worked for me. Simple solution. I put <Directory> directive to my apache site config. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me (thanks to @Ankur Loriya and many others to get me there)...

Go to the directory with your `index.html` file.

```
sudo nano .htaccess
```

Add this to the file:

```
RewriteEngine On
    # If an existing asset or directory is requested go to it as it is
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]
    # If the requested resource doesn't exist, use index.html
RewriteRule ^ /index.html
```

Exit Nano (Control+X) and save your changes (Y).

```
cd /etc/apache2
sudo nano apache2.conf
```

At the bottom of the file, there's a series of `<Directory>` tags.  Find the one that reads:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

...and change `AllowOverride None` to `AllowOverride All`

Exit Nano (Control+X) and save your changes (Y).

I'm not sure if the following command is needed, but I did it:

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

Finally, restart Apache:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

And that did it.