# When refreshing page Error message "The requested URL was not found on this server."

Tags: angular, url-routing, angular2-routing, production-environment

I uploaded to production my first Angular project.
The website available here: http://urigross.com
When I type in the address field "urigross.com" the website works fine.
When I refresh the page I get an error message. It also happens when I type in the address field the exact route such as "www.urigross.com/heb/about" for example. It happens with every route that I try.
Error message  Are :

"Not Found
The requested URL was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request."

I tried contacting the site support and they told me that **my angular routing may be not configured right**.
The website works perfectly locally on my pc with "ng s" command.
I tried searching on stackoverflow but the results were for php and not angular projects.

my routing code:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from 'src/app/components/home/home.component';
import { AboutComponent } from 'src/app/components/about/about.component';
import { ContactComponent } from 'src/app/components/contact/contact.component';
import { Page404Component } from 'src/app/components/page404/page404.component';
import { PlywoodHomeComponent } from 'src/app/components/plywood/plywood-home/plywood-home.component';
import { MdfHomeComponent } from 'src/app/components/mdf/mdf-home/mdf-home.component';
import { TegoHomeComponent } from 'src/app/components/tegoShuttering/tego-home/tego-home.component';
import { HardwoodsHomeComponent } from 'src/app/components/hardwood/hardwoods-home/hardwoods-home.component';
import { MapComponent } from 'src/app/components/map/map.component';
import { OsbFjHomeComponent } from 'src/app/components/OsbFj/osb-fj-home/osb-fj-home.component';


const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'heb/home', component: HomeComponent},
  { path: 'heb/about', component: AboutComponent},
  { path: 'heb/plywood1', component: PlywoodHomeComponent},
  { path: 'heb/mdf', component: MdfHomeComponent},
  { path: 'heb/hardwood', component: HardwoodsHomeComponent},
  { path: 'heb/plywood2', component: TegoHomeComponent},
  { path: 'heb/plywood3', component: OsbFjHomeComponent},
  { path: 'heb/contact', component: ContactComponent},
  { path: 'heb/map', component: MapComponent},
  { path: 'heb/page404', component: Page404Component},
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/heb/home', pathMatch: 'full' },  // Default redirect ( When inserting Domain name).
  // { path: '**', component: Page404Component }
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '/heb/page404', pathMatch: 'full'}  // Redirect when invalid address typed


];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class RoutingModule { }
```

Answer (score 9):

Your server is Apache. You can fix this with `.htaccess` This happens because you have client side routing but when direct hit to server the web server is unaware of the routes.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
```

from [here](https://www.sej-ko.dk/2017/03/29/routing-single-page-application-on-apache-with-htaccess/)

I have done similar for one of my React based SPA, should work for your Angular app also

Comment: Thank you so much. It's working. I simply created this file and uploaded it to the main site folder.

Comment: I've added a .htaccess file to my server's html folder, but I still have the problem. Should the file go somewhere else?

Comment: @RyanLoggerythm which webserver are you using? `html` could be correct location, but this can vary with web server configurations

Comment: hi @kiranvj, I'm using 2.4, and I just needed to enable "AllowOverride" in the apache2.conf file, documented here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35689696/apache-with-angular2-404-not-found/71004249#71004249

Comment: @RyanLoggerythm so thats it. The usage of `.htaccess` is not permitted initially. Good to know it worked. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24497749/httpd-conf-allowoverride-all) if you want `.htaccess` in only one folder. There will be a slight performance improvement if you target only a specific folder.

Answer (score 0):

The server needs to be configured to send index.html as a response for 404, because this is the only html file in angular. This is taken care of by Angular cli in development.

Also check the location strategy

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. 
How do I configure sending index.html as a response for 404? I tried searching the web a proper example for how to do it but I didn't find any.

Comment: it might depend on the the type of server you use and the way it can be configured. Please check the internet accordingly or post the server you are using

Comment: I used an Apache server. I just created the .htaccess file like kiranvj advised and all worked good sinse.

Answer (score 0):

[this answer by @kiranvj](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63468722/2176582) solved the problem for me too. But I had one crucial observation.

If you have sub-domains on the server, adding the code snippet in his answer to the `.htaccess` file in the root public folder, it will have an effect on all the sub-domains.

If you want a different effect on a particular sub-domain, you can make changes to the `.htaccess` file in the root folder of that sub-domain.

Answer (score 0):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <FilesMatch "\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|swf|js|css)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800, public"
    </FilesMatch>

    # Compress HTML, CSS, JavaScript, Text, XML and fonts
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/vnd.ms-fontobject
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-opentype
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-otf
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-truetype
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-ttf
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/opentype
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/otf
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/ttf
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/x-icon
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml

    # Remove browser bugs (only needed for really old browsers)
    BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
    BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
    BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
    Header append Vary User-Agent

    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).